# Setting up ruby-graphql: UserType not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I'm trying to make graphql-ruby working on my rails app. So far I got everything set up more or less, but when I go to the /graphiql page in my browser, I don't have access to my custom UserType (the predefined test case worked before, though. I'm getting this error message in the network tab of the developer tools:
*NoMethodError in GraphqlController#execute
undefined method `UserType' for #
GraphQL::Define::TypeDefiner:0x007fa3728b2348*

Can you help me?

My schema is defined as following: (leaves_messenger_schema.rb)

```
LeavesMessengerSchema = GraphQL::Schema.define do
  mutation(Types::MutationType)
  query(Types::QueryType)
end
```

My UserType is defined as follows: (types/user_type.rb)

```
Types::QueryType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name "Query"

  field :viewer, types.UserType do
    resolve ->(obj, args, ctx) {
      ctx[User.last]
    }
  end
end
```

and my UserType (types/user_type.rb):

```
Types::UserType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name 'User'
  description 'A user'

  field :id, types.String
  field :email, types.String
end
```

my routes.rb is defined as per generator. That should be correct since I can navigate to the graphiql page and the test case worked.

Thanks a lot for any advice you can give me!

Comment: Oh, and I know I should probably write UserType = instead of Types::UserType =, I just tried that to see if it helps. The former version shows the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you made a typo, try to change your code from this

`field :viewer, types.UserType do` to  `field :viewer, Types::UserType do`

Comment: cool! Yes, it works. That makes more sense definitely :) I had still not quite understood how everything works and the documentation had something with type.UserType in it, but I guess then I have to format something differently somewhere else. Thanks!